# Howto replace a string containing a dollar character for mysql with RegularExpressions?

Tags: regex, vb.net, escaping

I try to replace a value for a MySQL INSERT INTO string. This value contains a $ character at the begin and at the end. The $-character at the end and the closing '-Character get lost during the regex.Replace

This is my VB.NET code:

```
    Dim RawString As String = "$ Million's of Dollar Company $"
    Dim EscapedValue As String = MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString(RawString)

    Dim mySQLCommand As String = "INSERT INTO `companies` (`name`, `contact`) VALUES (@name, @contact)"

    Dim pattern As String = "@name"
    Dim replacement As String = "'" + EscapedValue + "'"
    Dim regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern)

    mySQLCommand = regex.Replace(mySQLCommand, replacement)
```

The expected result is:

```
"INSERT INTO `companies` (`name`, `contact`) VALUES ('$ Million\'s of Dollar Company $', @contact)"
```

Do you know the reason, why I get this wrong result (missing $' at the end of the first value?)

```
"INSERT INTO `companies` (`name`, `contact`) VALUES ('$ Million\'s of Dollar Company , @contact), @contact)"
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: no answer to your question: just an obsservation - stop using mysql. not sure if it's still the case, but once i tried to use multiple primary keys and i was told it doesn't support it and given like 3 different 'hacks'... rofl... mysql = hack :\

Comment: Can you output `EscapedValue` to see what's in there?

Comment: ah yes, so $ is terminating the string. that matches the end. why isn't it terminating at first $ though? no idea. but it seems that's what's happening. regex.. will never understand..

Comment: or supposedly, before any line break... not technically the end of a string...

Comment: @miindlek `EscapedValue` contains "$ Million\'s of Dollar Company $". `replacement` contains "'$ Million\'s of Dollar Company $'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.NET the dollor sign has a special meaning if you use it in the replacement string (used for substitution), see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh194617%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#substitutions).

You have to escape the dollor sign with another dollor sign, so that it looks like

`$$ Million's of Dollar Company $$`

So change the specific line in your code to:

```
Dim replacement As String = "'$" + EscapedValue + "$'"
```

For a more generic version, you could change your RawString like this:

```
Dim regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\$")
Dim NewRawString As String = regex.Replace(RawString, "$$$$")
```

Each `$` will be replaced by `$$`.

Comment: That works perfect for this specific case. Now I'm looking for a more generic version, that works for `Micro$$oft` or `$$$AP` as content of RawString too.